# How to use mssql datetimeoffset column type in yii2 framework

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, yii2, datetimeoffset

I am writing an application that needs to store dates with time and timezone and it needs to use mssql.

The `yii2` framework column schema for mssql defines only datetime column type, and no datetimeoffset.

What are possible approaches to this situation?

If I was to extend Yii2 orm to support a new column type and map `datetimeoffset` columns to `\DateTime` classes, how should I approach this "the `yii2` way"?

EDIT:

It seems that the problem is rather in migrations only, as

```
$this->createTable('{{%table_with_datetimeoffset}}', [
        'dtm' => $this->dateTime()->null()
]);
```

results in a column of type `datetime2`, and I need `datetimeoffset`.

Answer (score 1):

I can not write a comment, so I write here.
I found [this](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-mssql-schema) and I see `'datetimeoffset' => self::TYPE_DATETIME,` at $typeMap public property , is this what you are looking for?
You can post at their [forum](https://forum.yiiframework.com/) also.

Comment: Thanks, I've missed that. It seams that the type is supported if already in database, but in migration `$this->dateTime()` creates a `datetime2` column.